# BoringSSL Certificate Compression

Tags: openssl, rfc, boringssl

I was looking for a [RFC8879](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8879) implementation and found out that BoringSSL has it implemented.

However I haven't found out how can I enable this feature, since the certificate is not compressed by default and there is no parameter in the BoringSSL's TLS client for that.

Does anyone have already worked with this and can give me some help?

Answer (score 0):

```
SSL_CTX_add_cert_compression_alg(SSL_CTX *ctx, uint16_t alg_id,
                                     bssl::CertCompressFunc compress,
                                     bssl::CertDecompressFunc decompress)
```

You need to set pair of callbacks for each algorithm. ZLIB has index 1, BROTLI 2, ZSTD 3.

Comment: Ohh thanks! But where can I found these callback functions for each algorithm?

Comment: @JoãoPedroNascimento you mean code of these functions or signatures?

Comment: I guess that i'm going need to import from a compression library, right?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xpahos/66a8a7d7639386330bf0af8006d73bcf Code samples for compression/uncompression zlib/brotli/zstd.